# Store images in MS-Access Database using Delphi6

Tags: image, delphi, ms-access

How to Store images in the MS-Access Database using Blob data type?
I want to use Record Type to store data. So, how to handle image in Record Type to save in database?

Edit:
I want to store data with Image.
I have following Record Type:

```
type
  TPersonInfoRecType = Record
     FirstName: string[20];
     MiddleName: string[20];
     LastName: string[20];
     DateOfBirth: TDateTime;
     Age: integer;
     Gender: string[8];
     Mobile: string[11];
     LandLine: string[13];
     Adderss1: string[50];
     City: string[15];
     State: string[20];
     Country: string[20];
     ZipCode: string[6];
     Photo: TBlobField;
  end;
```

Comment: What you mean by _record type_, can you show your actual type declaration?

Comment: @jachguate, i have added _RECORDD TYPE_ in question.

Comment: I don't get the idea.. from where do you get the Photo reference? Remember we don't have a clue of what are you trying to do, so is up to yo to explain the context in your question. Take some time to read [how to write the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints)

Answer (score 1):

one possebility, which would allow storing diffent types of Images, you can shorten or expand the list in RegisterClasses.

```
unit LoadSaveImageBlobs;

// 20120224 by Thomas Wassermann

interface
uses Classes,DB,Graphics,Jpeg,PngImage;

Procedure SavePicture2Blob(Blob: TBlobField; Picture: TPicture);
Procedure LoadPictureFromBlob(Picture: TPicture; Blob: TBlobField);
implementation

Procedure SavePicture2Blob(Blob: TBlobField; Picture: TPicture);
var
  ms, ms2: TMemoryStream;
  theClassName: AnsiString;
  len: Byte;
begin
  ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    Blob.Clear;
    theClassName := Picture.Graphic.ClassName;
    len := Length(theClassName);
    ms.WriteBuffer(len, 1);
    if len > 0 then
      ms.WriteBuffer(theClassName[1], len);
    ms2 := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      Picture.Graphic.SaveToStream(ms2);
      ms2.Position := 0;
      if ms2.Size > 0 then
        ms.CopyFrom(ms2, ms2.Size);
    finally
      ms2.Free;
    end;
    Blob.LoadFromStream(ms);
  finally
    ms.Free;
  end;
end;

Procedure LoadPictureFromBlob(Picture: TPicture; Blob: TBlobField);
var
  ms, ms2: TMemoryStream;
  len: Byte;
  theClassName: AnsiString;
  Graphic: TGraphic;
  GraphicClass: TGraphicClass;
begin
  ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Blob.SaveToStream(ms);
  ms.Position := 0;
  try
    ms.ReadBuffer(len, 1);
    SetLength(theClassName, len);
    if len > 0 then
      ms.ReadBuffer(theClassName[1], len);
    GraphicClass := TGraphicClass(FindClass(theClassName));
    if (GraphicClass <> nil) and (len > 0) then
    begin
      Graphic := GraphicClass.Create;
      ms2 := TMemoryStream.Create;
      try
        ms2.CopyFrom(ms, ms.Size - len - 1);
        ms2.Position := 0;
        Graphic.LoadFromStream(ms2);
      finally
        ms2.Free;
      end;
      Picture.Assign(Graphic);
    end;
  finally
    ms.Free;
  end;
end;


initialization
RegisterClasses([TIcon, TMetafile, TBitmap, TJPEGImage,TPngImage]);

end.
```

Comment: i have passed 'PersonInfoRec.Photo' as TBlobField in SavePicture2Blob procedure, but getting error: Access Violation at addresss 004ACC5A in module. at second line: 'Blob.clear;'

Comment: Field is TBlobfield? Field is assigned? Dataset.State is in [dsEdit,dsInsert]?